# emptyView for CollectionView is never hidden

Tags: ember.js, collectionview

I have a `CollectionView` that has :

- a tagName set to `tbody` ( so its children are 'tr' )
- an `emptyView`.

The problem is: the `emptyView` is never hidden.

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EHQLF/

So my questions are :

1. Why is the `emptyView` still here after click on "add"
2. Why does it works if I remove the `tagName`
3. I want the render of the emptyView to look like this:

`<table><tr><td colspan="2">The collection is empty</td></tr></table>`

What is the proper way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
It works if the emptyView template start with `td`.

The emptyView is automatically tagged `tr` ( see [CollectionView.arrayDidChange()](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/collection_view.js#L265) and below `CollectionView.createChildView`).

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EHQLF/1/

I'm still interested for any other solution !